# Where should I start My Hero Academia manga after season 4?

Tags: my-hero-academia

*My Hero Academia* just finished its fourth season. I wanted to read its manga ahead.

So, where does Season 4 end in the manga so that I can start reading from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little research and found that **season 4** of **My Hero Academia** ends at chapter **190** in the manga, so for those who want to read the manga after season 4 ends, start from chapter **191**.

Season 5 will probably start from ch.191 onwards.