# Which chapter of the manga does Season 5 of My Hero Academia anime start in?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I've just seen the trailer of Season 5 of the anime My Hero Academia released 3 months ago, and I'm assuming that by knowing in which chapter of the manga Season 4 of the anime ends, you can know which chapter of the manga Season 5 starts.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 5 of My Hero Academia anime start?

Comment: Related: [Where should I start My Hero Academia manga after season 4?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/57168/2516), but this only tells the end of Season 4, not the start of Season 5.

Comment: Season 5 should start from chapter 191, but we don't know if the direction crew chooses to start with some filler parts, flashbacks or other parts of the story.